# YouTube API does not return if the channel is live or not

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

The goal of my YouTube API call is, given a **channelId**, return whether that channel is currently live streaming or not. I'm using this currently:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&eventType=live&type=video&key={API_KEY}
```

In the result if **items[]** is empty, I conclude it's live, else offline.

This is not working with my channel ID. The channel is going live, but the api call returns null for items[]. But It's working when I provide some other popular channel's ID. (for example this channel: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCe_3CoEeinvPMze2u_aENBg)

I obtained channel ID from the page's source code. See: [How can I get a channel ID from YouTube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366648/how-can-i-get-a-channel-id-from-youtube)

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310972/using-youtube-api-v3-to-tell-if-a-channel-has-a-live-stream

Comment: Use the liveStreams.list to check the status of a givin streamid look for the status object .. in the status object you will find the actual status of the livestream. I have the code with nodejs