# Can we know if we are streaming with youtube api?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

i trying to know if my channel is streaming on youtube. I'm using the youtube api v3 with the php library.
I'm able to get the last broadcasts with liveBroadcasts.list but when I start streaming with OBS I put the parameters broadcastStatus = active and nothing is returned. 
I also tried with liveStreams.list but I still get nothing. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, can someone explain me please ? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the [`search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#top_of_page), Here you can set the optional parameters to search what you need. Like the `channelId`, `eventType` that you can set to live to include active broadcast, and `type` parameter that restricts a search query to only retrieve a particular type of resource.

Read the other [`parameters`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) to know more about its purpose and description.

For more information you can also check this SO question:

- [Using YouTube API v3 to tell if a channel has a live stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310972/using-youtube-api-v3-to-tell-if-a-channel-has-a-live-stream)
- [How to check if YouTube channel is streaming live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454238/how-to-check-if-youtube-channel-is-streaming-live)

Answer (score 0):

The request url is :

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=id%2Csnippet%2Cstatus&mine=true&broadcastStatus=active&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

you should receive :

```
{"status":{ "lifeCycleStatus":"live"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the search API - something like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&channelId={CHANNEL_ID_YOU_WANT_TO_QUERY}&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}&eventType=live
```

However, this might take 3-5 minutes before it shows the Video ID of broadcast video after the broadcast has started. This has been discussed in another StackOverflow Question: [Using YouTube API v3 to tell if a channel has a live stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310972/using-youtube-api-v3-to-tell-if-a-channel-has-a-live-stream)